# Android studio - package sun.misc does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio, reactivex

I am new to Android and Java development. While I am importing some 3rd part library from GitHub, it requires the rx (ReactiveX) package. While building the codes from ReactiveX, it complains that package `sun.misc` does not exist. The rx package is using `Unsafe` here.

My Android Studio version is 1.5.1
I tried both Java 1.8.0_73 and 74, they did not work.
However, I have no problem importing `sun.misc.Unsafe` when creating a Java project in Netbeans 8.1 in Windows.

My JDK is 64bit.

I tried to search for the internet but I did not find the answer. Please help.

Comment: Post your build.gradle.

Answer (score 2):

sun.misc is a proprietary package that is used to provide some features in Java, like Unsafe operations you mentioned. It's not even reliable to use it in Java code since its not guaranteed that package will be available in next Java versions.

Since android was created by Google, I have strong doubts that this package is available for android apps.